# Using @provide and @Inject in the same class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, android-moxy

I try library [cicerone](https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone).
The [sample](https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone/tree/master/sample) use MOXY.
I cant undestend why we should [use](https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/ru/terrakok/cicerone/sample/ui/start/StartActivity.java) @ProvidePresenter and @InjectPresenter in the same class, and dont use it anywhere.

```
@InjectPresenter
StartActivityPresenter presenter;

private Navigator navigator = new SupportAppNavigator(this, -1);

@ProvidePresenter
public StartActivityPresenter createStartActivityPresenter() {
    return new StartActivityPresenter(router);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@InjectPresenter tells moxy, where should be placed Presenter. @ProvidePresenter tells how to create instance of this Presenter. Also, @ProvidePresenter will be called one time. But presenter field will be initialized after each activity restart.